# Drag and Drop Holding the Header Part

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In This i am able to drag by holding any where from the panel, But i want to drag the panel by holding on header part. and when i am dragging i can see scroll bar scrolling, i tried to made scroll bar to false , but total functionality getting failed to move

http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/qwmqC/6/

```
$(function() {
    $("#container").sortable(
        handle: 'h1',
        cursor: 'move',
        scroll: false,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        tolerance: 'pointer'

    )
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, you mean that when you drag inside of your container you get a scrollbar?

Comment: 1)I am able TO drag a panel by clicking anywhere of panel, but i want only by holding the header part i can able to drag                                                                   2)When i am dragging the panel i can see scroll bar scrolling i  want to disable scroll bar,i tried with many codes but getting failed

Comment: with your code above that should work? is it not working? you're already defining a `handle`.

Comment: Yes but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/qwmqC/7/

Comment: you forgot to add the brackets around the sortable call, posted an answer and demo below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your problem, you forgot to add a bracket around your `sortable` call, try this:

```
$("#container").sortable({
  handle: 'h1',
  cursor: 'move',
  scroll: false,
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  tolerance: 'pointer'
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwmqC/8/

Comment: Ya, But still my Scroll Bar is displaying when i drag the panels

Comment: @user178900 the scrollbar appears because when you place a box over the current top box it stacks all the boxes one in top of the other instead of shifting them to the side and reorganizing them, this is what the `containment: 'parent'` option tries to fix but you need to have a container that is properly contained for it to work.

Comment: Hi, I tried with this "Parent" key, hear when we try dragging, then i can find only second row second colum selecting always , and it is not flexiable to move so i just looking so some other values for "containment"

Comment: @user178900 you can remove the `placeholder: 'placeholder'` option to make it look more flexible. About the containment option, you can pass a selector to be used for containment, though `parent` is the one that is recommended, so if your box is included inside a bigger container you can select that as well.